# Why does pandas.apply(id, axis=1) return the same id for all rows?

Tags: pandas, apply, pass-by-reference, undefined-behavior, undocumented-behavior

I'm actually facing some problem I cannot understand. Imagine this scenario:

```py
df_mock = pd.DataFrame({'v': [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]})

class O:
  def __init__(self, row):
    self.row = row
    
  def calc(self):
    self.v = self.row.v

df_mock['obj'] = df_mock.apply(lambda row: O(row), axis=1)
df_mock['obj'].apply(lambda o: o.calc())
print(df_mock['obj'].apply(lambda o: o.v))
```

When I run this, I get:

```
0    [7, 8, 9]
1    [7, 8, 9]
2    [7, 8, 9]
Name: obj, dtype: object
```

But I expected that a reference to each row gets copied in the obj `O.row`. However, for some reason, after the `apply`, the last reference is kept in the objects of all rows.

Why does this happen? Does `pandas.apply(axis=1)` make some kind of unique reference for all rows and passes the current row as the same reference?

It can be seen much simpler if you just run:

```
df_mock.apply(id, axis=1)
```

It will output the same id for all cases

```
0    139938239801360
1    139938239801360
2    139938239801360
dtype: int64
```

Comment: When you pass in `O(row)` and do `self.row = row`, I believe you're setting the row attribute to the reference of the row object, which changes at every iteration. It works if you change to: `self.row = row[:]`

Comment: doing `row[:]` is the same as doing `row.copy()`, which of course solves the problem. The question I have is why even if the row is passed as reference, every iteration of the `.apply` ends up setting the same reference?

Comment: I think you answer the question yourself, it is how Pandas designs `apply`, which use the same (pointer) variable. Why? You should raise this question on [Pandas' GitHub page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas). To me it certainly is a bug, but Pandas devs may see otherwise.

Comment: Note that `df['obj']=[O(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]` works just fine. Another reason I favor explicit list comprehension over `apply`.

Comment: So officially, pandas has documented that `.apply()` is not intended to be used to mutate objects, because it may lead to undefined behavior (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), but I wanted to know why this happens.